# Remove duplicates from vec behind shared ref while doing additional work

Tags: rust

I have a couple structs:

```
struct FileView{
 name : String
 path : String
 //maybe other stuff
}
struct DirectoryView{
 files : Vec<FileView>
 //maybe other stuff
}
```

I want to write a function in the impl for DirectoryView which finds duplicates (by name), does some `fs` stuff to delete one of the paths, and updates the DirectoryView to remove the duplicate there as well.

This has been tricky due to restrictions around moving out of the shared reference, having mutable references into multiple points of the same data (like window functions), and the fact that the dedup function doesn't let me do additional stuff with the duplicates being purged. So far, the best I can do is:

```
fn purge_duplicates(&mut self) {
        self.files.sort_by(|a, b| a.name.cmp(&b.name));
        let mut prev_name = "rumplestilskin";
        let mut prev_path = "rumplestilskin";
        self.files.iter_mut().for_each(|file| {
            if file.name == prev_name {
                file.name = "DELETE_ME".to_owned();
                if file.path != prev_path {
                    std::fs::remove_file(&file.path).unwrap();
                }
            } else {
                prev_name = &file.name;
                prev_path = &file.path;
            }
        });
        self.files.retain(|file| file.name != "DELETE_ME");
    }
```

I don't like this - the magic "rumplestilskin" and "DELETE_ME" strings, the multiple passes, all strike me as messy. The only other options I've come up with are at least as bad, tho:

I can derive `Clone` for `FileView`, use a window to map into an all-new `Vec<FileView>` and assign `self.files` to that, but that doesn't feel much cleaner and only works for cloneable things.

I can mark indices of files to be removed and then iterate over those indices in reverse order.

I can be psychotically unwise and implement `Drop` for fileview in a way that deletes the file from disk when the view is destroyed. The only downside I see to this is that it's slightly more work than sticking my hard drive in the microwave, for comparable results.

Is there a good way to do this?

As a bonus question - I'd like a better way to ensure that I only delete the file on disk if the retained one has a different path. (i.e., I don't want to delete the only actual file just because it was referenced twice.)

Comment: `for_each` is unidiomatic here, even it's documentation recommends using a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple passes and the `"DELETE ME"` sentinel when you just directly do your work in retain, further instead of the `"rumplestilskin"` sentinel in Rust we use an enum, more specifically `Option`. I didn't want to conjure your `FileView` (and frankly it's wrong to use `String` for file and path names) so I use `PathBuf` instead, cloning them is unproblematic here, because the file system operation will dwarf it's runtime cost:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
fn purge_duplicates(files: &mut Vec<PathBuf>) {
    files.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| a.file_name().cmp(&b.file_name()));
    let mut previous = None::<PathBuf>;
    files.retain(|file| match previous {
        Some(ref prev)
            if file.file_name() == prev.file_name() && file.parent() != prev.parent() =>
        {
            if !file.is_symlink() && prev.is_symlink() {
                println!("remove_file({})", prev.display());
                previous = Some(file.clone());
            } else {
                println!("remove_file({})", file.display());
            }
            false
        }
        _ => {
            previous = Some(file.clone());
            true
        }
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut files = vec![
        PathBuf::from("first/one"),
        PathBuf::from("first/one"),
        PathBuf::from("second/one"),
        PathBuf::from("first/two"),
        PathBuf::from("second/two"),
    ];

    purge_duplicates(&mut files);
    
    println!("remaining: {:?}", files);
}
```

prints:

```
remove_file(second/one)
remove_file(second/two)
remaining: ["first/one", "first/one", "first/two"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that works! BTW, why did you specify `sort_unstable`?

Comment: Oh, part of my problem was that there might be other things in `FileView` that made it undesirable to clone it, but that's fine, nothing forces `previous` to be of the same type as `file` so that's an easy change if needed.

Comment: It's a good default to use `sort_unstable` over just `sort`, you rarely need a stable sort (one that preserves the order of equally evaluated items from before).